# execute user input as shell command in C

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

can any one tell me how to execute input of c program as command in shell?

I tried with the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>


    void main()
    {
    int year,month;
    system("date");
    printf("Enter the month and year\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&month,&year);
    system("cal &&");
    printf("%d %d",month,year);
    system("ls");
    system("ps");
    }
```

it has to print the calender of month and year provided by user

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass user inputs to bash as below;

```
int year,month;
system("date");
printf("Enter the month and year\n");
scanf("%d%d",&month,&year);

char cmd[4096];
sprintf(cmd, "cal -m %d %d", month, year);
system(cmd);


printf("%d %d",month,year);
system("ls");
system("ps");
```

man cal ;

-m month
         Display the specified month.  If month is specified as a decimal number, it may be followed by the letter ‘f’ or ‘p’ to indicate the following or preceding month of that number, respectively.

Output;

```
...
```

[image]

```
...
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you :)